# Proof that 1/x + 1/y is distinct for distinct unordered pairs of (x,y), xy = k.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

Take xy = k, for nonzero k. There are many (x,y) that can satisfy this. However, how do I prove that the sums of the members of any two distinct, unordered pairs, is distinct? (This is an equivalent proof to the title question).

Comment: Hint:  $(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy$

Comment: Hi lulu; I'm can't see how that helps; is there a specific approach that would work?

Comment: Well...if $(x+y)$ and $xy$ are both known then you can compute $(x-y)^2$.  If we say wlog that $x≥y$ we can then take the square root and get $x-y$.  But if you know $x-y$ and $x+y$...

Comment: I think there's something I'm missing. If you could give me the proof, or the steps to get there, that would be nice. I've been working on this for a while, and I just don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Ok.  A numerical example.  Say $x+y=11$ and $xy=24$.  Then $(x-y)^2=121-96=25$.  If we assume that $x≥y$ we deduce that $x-y=5$  Adding that to $x+y=11$ we get $2x=16$ so $x=8,y=3$.  The point is that $x+y$ and $xy$ determine $x-y$, hence $x,y$.

Comment: Hi Lulu; I understand how to solve the systems of equations; however, I don't see how this is related to the proof; how do I know that, given two pairs (x,y), xy = k that x + y will always be distinct? How would I prove that there exist no other (x,y), with x + y = 11?

Comment: Because we solved for $x,y$!  The only choice we made was in declaring that $x≥y$ and that wasn't a real choice (if you had insisted that $y>x$ you'd just have found $y=8,x=3$ so the unordered pair is the same).  Aside from that we got a closed form for $x,y$ ($x=\frac 12 \times \left(\sqrt {(x+y)^2-4xy}+(x+y)\right)$)

Comment: Perhaps I'm not getting the interpretation... in the numerical example, I understand that, given x+y=11 and xy=24, we can find unique (x,y). How does that imply that, given only xy=24, that every (x,y) we find implies a different (x+y)? I had reached the conclusion of solving for x myself before, but I failed to see what it had to do with anything.

Comment: Here's the logic:  if you tell me $(x+y)$ and $xy$ then I can tell you the unordered pair $(x,y)$.  The closed formula I gave you only returns one value for the larger of $x,y$.  There can't be another pair $(x',y')$ because $x'$ would have to be given by the same closed formula!

Comment: OK! I think I get it now. Given xy = k, the possible (x+y) and unordered (x,y) form a bijection, based on what you're saying. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, almost.  Some data don't give a solution.  For example $xy=10,x+y=1$ would give us $(x-y)^2=1-40=-39$ which has no real solutions.

Comment: Yeah, but of the data that do, I believe I understand how exactly one x+y corresponds to exactly one (x,y) now. Thanks for the help/patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the discussion in the comments:  suppose that $x+y=S$ and $xy=k$ are given.  We claim that this data specifies the pair $(x,y)$ up to order.

Indeed, declaring $x$ to be the larger of the two we easily see that $$2x=\sqrt {S^2-4k}+S$$.

Just to emphasize, if $(x',y')$ was a another pair with $x'≥y',x'+y'=S,x'y'=k$ then the same algebra would show that $$2x'=\sqrt{S^2-4k}+S=2x\implies x'=x$$